# What is the font used in this concept for the Battle.net promo page?

Tags: font-identification

I'd like to know whether someone knows which font has been used in the following pictures since all font recognition tools haven't yielded any results.

What is interesting is the skewed line in the uppercase A as well as the unique uppercase B and most notably of all the odd "dot" above the lowercase i.

[image]
[image]

The full concept (which was too long to include into this post) can be seen on [Dribble](https://dribbble.com/shots/2361361-Battle-Net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Expo Sans Pro](http://typeculture.com/foundry/font-collection/expo-sans-pro/) via typeculture.com

[image: expo sans]

Info extracted from [Behance.com](https://www.behance.net/gallery/31376221/BattleNet)

[image: FOnt Info]

Comment: Nice work! It also looks a lot like Polo by Georg Salden, and several Erik Spiekermann typefaces: Meta, Officina and the free Fira Sans. Those could be good choices if you wanted something like this but a bit more serious-looking.